# How to track the number of application run in a particular time interval?

Tags: blackberry

I want to track that how many applications run in the particular time interval in blackberry curve 8900. Please let me know the API to program this?

Answer (score 2):

try following code

```
ApplicationDescriptor[] ad = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager()
                .getVisibleApplications();
        int numberOfApplication = ad.length;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The functionality is "When my application sstarts I want to take the user input as time interval and then I'll show the number of application run in the given interval". Could you please suggest how can I get this functionality.